# How to add security for spring 5 websockets

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket

I followed the following tutorial: [Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Everything works as described and aplication looks fine. I just have a nice controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {    

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }

}
```

And a bit configuration.

Now I want to add security for this simple application. I spent time to find an example but I could not find it.

Generally I've found the tutorial:

[Preview Spring Security WebSocket Support](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support)

But looks like this example relevant for spring 4 only rather than spring 5. And I don't understand where should I provide credentials and so on. Description is not enough detailed to apply it for my example.

One more tutorial I've found:
[Websocket Authentication and Authorization in Spring
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405332/websocket-authentication-and-authorization-in-spring?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It looks more clear but I am not sure that it is the best solution for now.

Can you advise the simplest way to configure spring security for my application?

**P.S.** Also I've found not the same but familiar question [How to secure websocket application [Spring boot + STOMP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903044/how-to-secure-websocket-application-spring-boot-stomp) but there are no answers at the moment.

### UPDATE for **locus2k**

Now I have following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private static String[] authorities = new String[]{
            "VIEW_SCRIPT_TAB", "VIEW_CREDS_TAB"
    };

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket")
                .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Handshake interceptor beforeHandshake");
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                        System.out.println("Handshake interceptor after");
                    }
                })
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry message) {

        message
                .nullDestMatcher().permitAll()
                .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasAnyAuthority(authorities)
                .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**").permitAll()
                .anyMessage().denyAll();
    }
}
```

Bit when I start application I see stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler]: Factory method 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler]: Factory method 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler]: Factory method 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]    
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler]: Factory method 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [com/my/ws/example/ws_example/hello/WebSocketConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 136 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.createMetadataSource(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.java:242) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer$WebSocketMessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.createMetadataSource(AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java:193) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource(AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java:179) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.my.ws.example.ws_example.hello.WebSocketConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ebc3c92.CGLIB$inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource$6(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.my.ws.example.ws_example.hello.WebSocketConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ebc3c92$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d713310.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.my.ws.example.ws_example.hello.WebSocketConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ebc3c92.inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 137 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I saw that bounty on the question you linked, did my answer help? I want to ensure before providing a similar answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided stacktrace related with the incompatible library versions.

It works if to use correct dependencies. For example:

```
compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:5.0.4.RELEASE')
compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web: 5.0.4.RELEASE')
```

Answer (score 2):

The posts you linked works for Spring 5 websockets as well and is the simplest solution to extend
`AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp")
      .setAllowedOrigins("*")
      .withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry message) {
    message
      .nullDestMatcher().permitAll()
      .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasAnyAuthority(authorities)
      .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/" + "**").permitAll()
      .anyMessage().denyAll();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
     return true;
   }    
}
```

The security check is performed in the `configureInbound` method and you'll have to tailor it to your application.

The `authorties` is a string array object defining what is authorized for example:

```
private static String[] authorities = new String[] {
  "VIEW_SCRIPT_TAB", "VIEW_CREDS_TAB"
};
```

These authorities are what you define in your `GrantedAuthorty` object.

If you did not use `GrantedAuthorty` then you can remove that object.

Make sure you include the spring-security-config dependency in your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't find dependency for class **AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer**

Comment: Now I have: *compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:4.0.1.RELEASE')*

Comment: `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer ` Is in the spring-security-config dependency. See my edit

Comment: In method **configureInbound**,  **authorities** could not be resolved

Comment: Also I can't find dependency with class **WebsocketOutboundChannelInterceptor**

Comment: See my edits, as far as `WebsocketOutboundChannelInterceptor ` goes you can remove that override its not needed and was a custom class I created. `authorties` is an object that defines authorities assigned. If you do not use `GrantedAuthority` you can remove that line as well.

Comment: How can I understand whether I use GrantedAuthority or not?

Comment: `GrantedAuthority` is used in an Authentication Provider. Are you using any components that implements `AuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169767/discussion-between-locus2k-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: I don't have any components that implements `AuthenticationProvider`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was;

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource**

I realized the following dependency was missing. I added it and then it worked for me (version is inherited from parent Spring pom.xml).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```