# Adding Cookie to Request Header of a Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The issue I have is `Cookie` is not added to the request header therefore I receive a 403 status. To explain further I am implementing a system [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648098/what-does-cookie-csrftokenrepository-withhttponlyfalse-do-and-when-to-use-it) where when a user opens a page, a request token is is fetched and added to the `META` of the html and also saved in the `document.cookie`. When the user decides to login, the fetch request below `fetchSignIn` should automatically add a cookie because I am setting `credentials: "include"` but it doesn't. I have looked at other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie) but I don't understand where my implementation is wrong.

Login implementation using OOP

```
class Login {
// Private methods...

    fetchSignIn (obj, url) {
        console.log("Cookie ", document.cookie);
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify(obj),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "",
                "X-XSRF-TOKEN": getQSelector('meta[name="_csrf"]').content
            }
        })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error: ', error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Fetch token on opening of the page

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    _loadCSRF(CSRFDOMLOAD);
})

const _loadCSRF = (path) => {
    fetch(path) // GET Request
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        document.cookie = data.headerName + "=" + data.token;
        getQSelector('meta[name="_csrf_header"]').setAttribute("content", data.headerName);
        getQSelector('meta[name="_csrf"]').setAttribute("content", data.token);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error("Failed csrf fetch ", err));
}
```

Comment: is `url` the same origin as the page making the request?

Comment: It is the same domain but using different path. To better explain ‘fetchSignIn’ url for example is localhosthost:8080/login and ‘_loadCSRF’ url is  localhosthost:8080/csrf @JaromandaX

Comment: all good, just wondered why you specifically added `mode: "cors"` to the request if it's NOT a cross origin request - but, is the PAGE served by "localhosthost:8080" or is "localhosthost:8080" just an API?

Comment: @JaromandaX How much you want to bet it's "I was just trying that to see if it would help"?

Comment: Oh it is cross domain. The server side is running on port: 8080 and client side 
127.0.0.1 @JaromandaX

Comment: well, that's why the cookie isn't being sent ... you set it on 127.0.0.1 so it won't be sent to "localhosthost:8080" ... cookies don't work like that

Comment: Just so I am clear, if an application is cross domain meaning client and server running on two different ports, one cannot send a cookie in the request header? @JaromandaX

Comment: "client and server running on two different ports" ... makes no sense and does not describe your situation... you have two servers ... one at `127.0.0.1` (presumably port 80, which seems to be where your HTML, Javascript is coming from) and one at `localhosthost:8080` - which is some sort of API, where your requests are being sent - they are not the same origin, so cookies you set in the javascript are set for the former, and are not sent to the latter